# How to refresh datatable on changing the data without refreshing the whole page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this HTML/PHP code for building the table:

```
echo '<table id="table" >';

    echo '<thead>'; 
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<th>#</th>';
            echo '<th>Name</th>';
            echo '<th>Location</th>';
            echo '<th>Website</th>';
            echo '<th>Actions</th>';
        echo '</tr>';
    echo '</thead>';

    echo '<tbody id="tableContent">';

        //Loop Through The Database Returned Data.
        foreach($values as $val){
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>' . $val['id'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $val['name'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $val['location'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>  . $val['website'] . </td>';
                echo '<td>
                    <button>Edit</button> 
                    <button>Delete</button>
                </td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }//End For Each.

    echo '</tbody>';

echo '</table>';
```

Then I have this Jquery Code to run Datatable Plugin:

```
var table =  $('#table').DataTable({
         "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]] ,
          "autoWidth": true,
        "responsive": true,
         "lengthChange": true,
          "ordering": true 
});
```

There are buttons to (ADD , Edit , Delete) and they are working but I have to refresh the table to see the changes.

I tried

```
table.destroy();
table.draw();
```

But the new table just contain 1 page without pagination and the filtering(searching) is not working.

-How to refresh it without refreshing the whole page?

-Is it possible to keep the same page , filtering before refreshing the table?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to see the updated table in the web page and not the actual database.
in this case try to put the code you want in a form and let the action of the form be # like:

```
<form action='#' method='POST'>
    your code
    maybe you'll let the user click a button too
</form>
```

hopefully that works!